# Фильтр по алфавиту

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите, можно ли с помощью WordPress реализовать фильтр по алфавиту. Допустим пользователь выбрал букву "А" и выводятся посты с первой буквой "А".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все можно. Установите плагин [Ajax Search Lite](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-search-lite/), там реализован такой функционал. Правда, живой поиск начинается только после ввода 3 первых букв.

Answer (score 1):

Простой метод - ставь нужному посту метку "А"